# Safary iframe laravel this page has expired

Tags: laravel, iframe, safari

I have a page in an iframe and it works in all browsers except safari

I have tried with a third part of cookies, i use a code in JS to set the cookies but still the same error, this is the code in js in which is placed where the iframe is placed

```
var is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
if ((is_chrome) && (is_safari)) {is_safari = false;}  
if (is_safari) {
    if (!document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?\s*fixed\s*=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/)) {
        document.cookie = 'fixed=fixed; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC; path=/';
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be looking into the consistency of the session.. and your csrf token

Comment: what do you mean by that? because in other browsers I work without inconvenience

Comment: First of all, that it works in other browsers is no guarantee at all that it should work in all browsers... And as far as I can see it should only do something in Safari, right?

Comment: yes only in safari :(

Comment: I meant, your code will only do something in Safari, therefore it will 'work' in any other browser..

Comment: is an iframe and the 40% of the user in the platafor use IOS and need it work in IOS

Comment: You're not getting my point... the code you posted does nothing if it isn't executed in Safari. That means that you cannot say the code will or won't work in another browser. (Really an iframe in IOS??). Looking at it doesn't this code clear and save a new cookie whenever it is executed?

Comment: yes I already understand what do you mean, I made an exception to the routes I occupy in the verifyToken and if it takes them but it does not store the session when it redirects me to the home

Comment: I'm guessing you got your code from [this](https://gist.github.com/iansltx/18caf551baaa60b79206) gist.. did you als use the 'child' bit inside your iframe?

Comment: no i'm not using child inside mine iframe

Comment: you should, otherwise the other code does nothing..